# How to say that a piece of wet cloth is visible through the other?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, slang, informal-language

How to say somebody that his underwear, like a singlet, is visible through his shirt? Like if his cloths are wet, but not necessarily wet only, and you can see what's under the shirt. Is 'visible' the only word for that?

Would be really great if you could bring a couple of examples.

This could be a formal or informal way of saying that. Ideal, if both. Thanks there!

Comment: I would call the cloth "see-through". I don't think there is a single word that means "See-through *because* it's wet".

Comment: There's [VPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panty_line) (visible panty line), but that's normally only used in contexts where the outer material is *stretched taut*, so what you're seeing is the raised outline of the undergarment. For your context (transparency caused by the outer fabric being wetted), ***see-through*** is a likely term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can say

Your underwear *can be seen through* your shirt.

Your underwear *is showing through* your shirt.

or just

Your underwear *is showing through*.